# "let" or "may" in a specific context?

Tags: word-choice

Tell me please which word I should use in the following context.

> The man is trying hard to change the country for the better. **May**/**let** he succeed!

What I want to convey by the word are a wish or hope. Does those have identical meanings in that, if not, then what is the difference?

Comment: Follow "let" with an object pronoun: me, you, him, her, us, you, them. May he.. is the one you want. Let him.. isn't a goodwill wish.

Answer (score 2):

Either is possible, but their grammar is different.

> May he succeed.

but

> Let him succeed.

*May* is a modal, and takes a verb (in the base form), not a clause. This is an inversion of *He may succeed*, used for wishes. Other than with *may*, the syntax is now obsolete except for a few set expressions like *Long live X!*

*Let* is not a modal, but a verb which takes an infinitive clause. It normally has as a subject the agency allowing the action, so *Let him succeed* is syntactically a command, and could be said to somebody who has the power to hinder the success. But it is also used in a more general way, and I think is now more common than the "may" construction for that purpose.

Comment: I'd say both versions are a bit "stilted, formal" (in normal conversational contexts, most people today would say ***I hope he succeeds***), but I think you're right that the ***may*** version is more "dated, poetic" than ***let***. I can just about imagine a teenager saying ***Let it be me**!* (to himself / his god) when eagerly hoping to be chosen for something, but ***May it be me**!* is just a bit *too* "Victorian".